# mysql left join complaning

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone please tell me what is syntactically wrong with this query?

The error message returned is not helping at all.

```
select P.test_result_calc_category, a.NumberofPatients from (select distinct test_result_calc_category FROM a1c) P 

left join

(select test_result_calc_category, count (distinct patient_id) as NumberofPatients from a1c group by test_result_calc_category) a 

ON P.test_result_calc_category = a.test_result_calc_category
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct patient_id) as NumberofPatients from a1c group by test_result_calc_cate' at line 5

Comment: What is the error message? MySQL has great error messages.

Comment: Added error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/function-resolution.html

You have a space after the function COUNT in `COUNT (DISTINCT ...`

There are rules about this. You should have no space before the `(` unless you set the `sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space after `count`

```
count(distinct patient_id)
     ^----------here
```

Comment: The one you like better.